# Nim hashtable mapping strings to any type

Tags: hashtable, nim-lang

How do I instantiate a hashtable in Nim that maps strings to objects of any type (including basic data types)? None of these seem to work:

```
import tables
var t = newTable[string, any]()
var t = newTable[string, ref]()
var t = newTable[string, auto]()
var t = newTable[string, object]()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Unlike in languages like Java, where everything is derived from `Object` and you can use that as base type, Nim does not have a single type where everything is derived from. There is `RootObj` which is used by most object-oriented types as base. However, that does not work for basic data types.

You can use [object variants](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-object-variants) which allow you to create a type which can hold one of several, differently typed values. Typically, this question arises with people that are used to scripting languages where mappings to *any type* are used all the time, but in practice it is seldom necessary. So most probably, there is another solution for what you want to do without the need of such a hashtable.